# Putting things into a queue when the queue is in a template?

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

Assume I had some binary search tree that worked and declared two like this:

```
BinaryTree<string, queue<int> > * tree1 = new BinaryTree<string, queue<int>>;
BinaryTree<string, int> * tree2 = new BinaryTree<string, int >;
```

And lets say for the second one this worked perfectly:

```
tree2->Add("Yoyo", 10);
```

How would you add values to the one that has the second parameter as queue?

Since usually you need to have some type of object declared to add to the queue, how do i do it in this sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your BinaryTree class is declared as

```
template <typename T, typename U>
class BinaryTree 
...
    Add(T, U);
```

I would guess you can only add a preconstructed queue

```
BinaryTree<string, queue<int>> tree;
tree.Add("foo", queue<int>());
// or
queue<int> q;
q.push_back(1);
...
tree.add("bar", q);
```

To modify the queue after it has been added, you would need an access method

```
template <typename T, typename U>
class BinaryTree 
...
    Add(T, U);
    U& Get(T);
```

to be used as

```
BinaryTree<string, queue<int>> tree;
tree.Add("foo", queue<int>());
tree.Get("foo").push_back(1); // Modifies queue at "foo"
```

Comment: So no possible way to push into the queue once it's embedded into that tree at all?

Comment: you would need to modify the BinaryTree class, I editet my answer to reflect the changes that are needed. You are very welcome

Comment: Can you point me in the correct direction of the technique you are using. What type of function is that? The one that returns the reference. I rarely see references returned. Is there any place I can read about exactly what the function you are making is?

Comment: You need to somehow access the data stored in the BinaryTree. The function Get i proposed returns a refernce to that internal data. How did you plan on accessing the stored data in the BinaryTree after you stored it with Add?

Comment: I have a function I have that can Get the Queue. It works really well. But I need to be able to push data into that queue and I have no way around that, no matter how hard I think. So I think the function you just proposed is my best option. I need to know how to push into it and create it.

Comment: Wait, I think I know what you are talking about. Are You talking about me getting the data and then using that get function to push into the queue? The thing is that it doesn't return a reference.

Comment: Can you post the source code for that function? I would guess, just returning a reference would suffice but I need to see the actual source to be sure

Comment: Ohhh wait. I get what you are saying. I need to create the same exact method, only with code which returns a reference to the data. I'm going to try it now and see if it works.